# SQL between two dates, where date is represented with integers

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure. If I want to get rows between two datetimes, I would use something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @dateTimeFrom AND @dateTimeTo;
```

How do you do that when your date in database is not datetime, but integer.

- Year = 2018, Month = 6, Day = 6

I tried conditional where like this:

```
WHERE 
    @fromYear <= GS.[Year] AND GS.[Year] <= @toYear 
    AND @fromMonth <= GS.[Month] AND GS.[Month] <= @toMonth 
    AND @fromDay <= GS.[Day] AND GS.[Day] <= @toDay
```

Not working how I expected.

I also tried this:

```
AND DATEFROMPARTS(GS.[Year], GS.[Month], GS.[Day]) BETWEEN CAST(@from AS date) AND CAST(@to AS date)
```

Edit: full procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stats] 
    @from VARCHAR(15) = NULL,
    @to VARCHAR(15) = NULL
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET nocount ON;

    DECLARE @fromYear INT = NULL;
    SET @fromYear = CASE WHEN @from IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(year, @from) END

    SELECT @fromYear

    DECLARE @fromMonth INT = NULL;
    SET @fromMonth = CASE WHEN @from IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(month, @from) END
    SELECT @fromMonth

    DECLARE @fromDay INT = NULL;
    SET @fromDay = CASE WHEN @from IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(day, @from) END

    SELECT @fromDay

    DECLARE @toYear INT = NULL;
    SET @toYear = CASE WHEN @to IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(year, @to) ELSE @fromYear END

    SELECT @toYear

    DECLARE @toMonth INT = NULL;
    SET @toMonth = CASE WHEN @to IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(month, @to) ELSE @fromMonth END

    SELECT @toMonth

    DECLARE @toDay INT = NULL;
    SET @toDay = CASE WHEN @to IS NOT NULL THEN Datepart(day, @to) ELSE @fromDay END

    SELECT @toDay

    SELECT 
        GS.[name]
    FROM   
        [dbo].[gamestatsdaily] AS GS 
    WHERE   
        (@from IS NULL OR (@fromYear <= GS.[Year] AND GS.[Year] <= @toYear 
                           AND @fromMonth <= GS.[Month] AND GS.[Month] <= @toMonth 
                           AND @fromDay <= GS.[Day] AND GS.[Day] <= @toDay))
    ORDER BY 
        GS.[year] ASC, GS.[month] ASC, GS.[day] ASC 
END
```

Data example:

```
Name        Day   Month     Year    
----------------------------------
Microsoft   24      5       2018    
Apple       12      7       2018    
Thor        13      8       2018
```

Comment: Do you have the option of altering the table's definition? Could you, for example, create a computed column?

Comment: I am using a procedure. I can build date from datefromparts.

Comment: What are the datatypes and values of @from and @to?

Comment: You can yes, however, using `DATEFROMPARTS` on your column will make the query non-SARGable; hence why I asked if you can alter the table definition (and specifically adding a computed column).

Comment: I can't alter the table. @squillman they are VARCHAR(15)

Comment: If its an integer, what does that look like exactly? Something like `732018`?

Comment: Why are you sorting a `int` as a `varchar`, especially a `varchar(15)`? The highest month number is `12` and the highest day is `31`, so a `varchar(2)` would suffic, but an `int` would be far better. I think, really, you need to actually be fixing your data definition here.

Comment: I added full procedure

Comment: Have any data examples for us?

Comment: If you don't want to change the table, use the DATEFROMPARTS function. You said that you already tested that and it went wrong, so the problem is the cast of the parameters to date. Most likely the regional settings of the server differ from your expectation. Try SET DATEFORMAT dmy before casting, or use the CONVERT function instead, this has a "style" parameter to specify the date format. But why not change the parameter types to datetime?

Answer (score 0):

As I've said in the comments, the real answer here is fixing your data definition. The answer covers using both `DATEFROMPARTS`, the "simple" answer, however, the "bad" answer as well; as the query will be non-SARGable. It also, however, has an answer that changes the datatype of the columns to `int`, which they should be, and then adds a `PERSISTED` computed column to the table, which can be queried:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO
CREATE TABLE SomeTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                        TheYear varchar(15), --Should be an int
                        TheMonth varchar(15), --Should be an int
                        TheDay varchar(15)); --Should be an int

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (TheYear,
                           TheMonth,
                           TheDay)
VALUES('2018','06','01'),
      ('2018','06','05'),
      ('2018','06','15'),
      ('2018','06','20'),
      ('2018','06','22'),
      ('2018','06','23'),
      ('2018','07','01'),
      ('2018','07','03');
GO

DECLARE @StartDate date, @EndDate date;

SET @StartDate = '20180620';
SET @EndDate = '20180630';
--Non SARGable answer:
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable
--A load of TRY_CONVERT because you've chosen a varchar to store an int. Thus your data can't be trusted to contain an int.
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(TRY_CONVERT(int,TheYear),TRY_CONVERT(int,TheMonth),TRY_CONVERT(int,TheDay)) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;
GO
--The real answer:
--Firstly, let's fix those data types:
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD TheYearI int;
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD TheMonthI int;
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD TheDayI int;
--And update the values
GO
UPDATE dbo.SomeTable
SET TheYearI = TRY_CONVERT(int,TheYear),
    TheMonthI = TRY_CONVERT(int,TheMonth),
    TheDayI = TRY_CONVERT(int,TheDay);
GO
--Drop the old columns
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable DROP COLUMN TheYear;
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable DROP COLUMN TheMonth;
ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable DROP COLUMN TheDay;
GO
--Rename the new columns
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.SomeTable.TheYearI','TheYear','COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.SomeTable.TheMonthI','TheMonth','COLUMN';
EXEC sp_rename 'dbo.SomeTable.TheDayI','TheDay','COLUMN';
GO
--Creat the new computed column

ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ADD TheDate AS DATEFROMPARTS(TheYear, TheMonth, TheDay) PERSISTED;
GO
--And now the simple query:
DECLARE @StartDate date, @EndDate date;

SET @StartDate = '20180620';
SET @EndDate = '20180630';

SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE TheDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
GO
```

Comment: year, day, month are int in table. i am passing varchar as date as parameter into stored proc above. I am passing this varchar as param '2018-06-02'

Comment: @AmelSalibasic Use a `date` for your parameter, not a `varchar`. a `varchar` is **not** a date. If you are storing your date parts, however, as a `int`, you can remove the `TRY_CONVERT`s and the column changes, however, I still suggest adding the `PERSISTED` computed column and then querying that. You'll get much better performance.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of method would likely work, but you really should be trying to fix that data.

```
;WITH Orders (Name, [Day], [Month], [Year]) AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        VALUES
            ('Microsoft', 24, 5, 2018),         
            ('Apple', 12, 7, 2018),         
            ('Thor', 13, 8, 2018)
    ) AS A (Name, [Day], [Month], [Year])
)

SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE Cast(STR([Month]) + '/' + STR([Day]) + '/' + STR([Year]) AS DATETIME)
BETWEEN '04/02/2018' AND '07/03/2018'
```

Comment: fields in table are int for year, month and day, and varchar(15) is parameter in stored procedure.

Comment: That's nasty, but I updated the answer. If I understand it correctly, that should be better.